# WMP: streaming, then saving

Tags: wmp

I use the Windows Media Player Control (WMP.DLL) in my application to download (stream) and show videos. Once the video file is fully downloaded, I would like to save it to disk. Unfortunately I can't find a way to do so. I thought of using a hack: probably WMP does not hold the whole file in memory, so it must be somewhere on disk as temp file - but where?

So, in short: does anybody know how to tell WMP control to save a streamed video to disk? (The Windows Media Player knows how to to it, it has a 'Save as' command, so there must be a way to do it.)

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to check the temporary internet files folder - the file might be there.

Answer (score 0):

That did it, thanks! I don't even have to search for the files manually , I can use *URLDownloadToFile*. If Windows finds the file in *Temporary Internet Files*, it just takes it from there instead of downloading it again. Problem solved!